# How to change setBounds for a while using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

i want to do such like this ... it is suitable for simple statements but in case of setting bounds only last statement executes

```
try{
    label.setBounds(40,50,150,150);
    obj.sleep(1000);
    label.setBounds(70,50,150,150);
    obj.sleep(1000);
    label.setBounds(100,50,150,150);
}
catch(Exception e){
//
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? do you want your label to change size every 1000 milliseconds?

Comment: Hard to answer when you provide so little context (e.g., when is that code executed?  What thread executes it?) But one thing is clear, there is no way for the last `setBounds(...)` to be executed unless the first two also were executed.  Probably what's happening is that no event happens that would cause the label to be repainted until sometime after all three calls complete.

Comment: @Misteradi1 i want to change the loaction of label

Comment: @jameslarge sir , i just want to change the  location of label for a while actually the thing is on pressing of button causes a change of label for while just want to show user that button pressed !

Comment: I can only guess at an answer.  If you want a real answer, you'll have to show more of your code.  My guess is, that your code snippet is in an event handler.  My guess is, that the GUI framework does not re-paint the label until after the handler returns.

Comment: yeah but sir actually my code is long cant show whole code i just want to produce movement in label  on pressing of button. can you guide me what should i do .thanks@jameslarge